# Read file content from SFTP location using WinSCP

Tags: c#, ftp, sftp, winscp, winscp-net

I need to read a file from SFTP location using WinSCP .NET assembly in C#.
I'm able to download file from SFTP location to local path and read it.
But is there a way to read the file content directly without downloading to local path?

Below is the code used for downloading. But I see no option available to read the file content directly in WinSCP... something like using response, stream etc...

```
TransferOptions objTransferoptions = new Transferoptions()
objTransferoptions.transfermode = Automatic
Session objsession = new Session()
objsession.Open()
objsession.GetFiles(remotepath, localpath, false,objTransferoptions)
```

Can someone please let me know, if it is possible to read file contents directly from SFTP location? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Session.GetFile`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_session_getfile) to download a remote file to memory.

```
using (Session session = new Session())
{
    // Connect
    session.Open(sessionOptions);
     
    using (var stream = session.GetFile(remotePath))
    {
        // now process the data in "stream" the same way you would
        // for example process a stream returned by System.IO.File.Open()
    }
}
```